# Create a repeat purchase matrix with respect to a customers first purchase date in python/pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have a data set about repeat customer purchases. The table gives details of what all dates the customer made a purchase and the No_Trans column indicates the nth purchase of a customer. All of them are repeat purchasers and the dates go on till 04/18/20. Below is a snapshot of the table

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|               Customer            | Trans_Date |No_Trans|
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
| C1                                | 3/15/20    |    1   |
| C1                                | 3/15/20    |    2   |
| C1                                | 3/17/20    |    3   |
| C2                                | 3/15/20    |    1   |
| C2                                | 3/17/20    |    2   |
| C3                                | 3/16/20    |    1   |
| C3                                | 3/18/20    |    2   |
| C4                                | 3/17/20    |    1   |
| C4                                | 3/18/20    |    2   |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

I need to create a matrix which gives the count of purchasers by first purchase dates and each of their repeat purchased by date something as below in python pandas

```
                                               +-------------------------------------------+ 
                                               |          Repeat Purchasers by date        |
 +------------------+--------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
 |     Date         | First purchasers on date | 3/15/20  |  3/16/20 |  3/17/20 |  3/18/20 |
 +------------------+--------------------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
 |   3/15/20        |            2             |    1     |    0     |     2    |     0    |
 |   3/16/20        |            1             |    0     |    0     |     0    |     1    |
 |   3/17/20        |            1             |    0     |    0     |     0    |     1    |
 |   3/18/20        |            0             |    0     |    0     |     0    |     0    |
 +------------------+--------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
```

- On 3/15/20 there were 2 customers C1 and C2 who made their first purchases, C1 made a repeat purchase again on 15th and on 17th and C2 on 17th. Hence 3/15/20 column is populated as 1 and 3/17/20 is summed as 2.
- On 3/16/20 there was one customer C3 who made a first purchase on 16th and made a repeat purchase on 18th hence 3/18/20 column is marked as 1.
- On 3/17/20 there was one customer C4 who made a first purchase on 17th and made a repeat purchase on 18th hence 03/18/20 column is marked as 1.
- No customers made a first purchase on 3/18/20.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Conceptually, you can groupby date and no_trans = 1 and count values. Then you can join that table with a pivot table of data filtered by no_trans > 1. Try some code and post what you've tried and where you've come short.

Comment: Thank you @EricTruett. I used your logic and was able to get the results. Much appreciated!